# Comparing columns within a group in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I'm very new to SQL so I appologize if this question is difficult to understand.

Let's say I have a table like:

```
Name    Birthday
Bob     7/18
Bob     7/18
Mark    5/10
Mark    7/5  
Sue     2/1
Joe     1/14
Joe     1/14
Joe     1/2
Jeff    9/16
Jeff    3/20
Jeff    6/13
[...]
```

I would like to perform a select statement that gives me the Names of the people who have more than one distinct Birthdays.

So, for my example table, the output would be Mark, Joe, and Jeff.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: run `select @@Version`, but saying `SQL Server 2008` is good enough

Comment: I surgest you test Dem's solution with my test data. You get Jake and Mark instead of Pete and Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A re-wording as I understand your problem statement:

All Names where:
- The name has more than one Colour associated to it
- Of those, at least two Colours have different birthday's associated to them

What I'm unsure of is whether it's possible to have two different birthdays for the same colour associated to the same name?

If `no`, the colour becomes irrelevant, you just want a name with more than 1 different birthday associated to it.

```
SELECT
  Name
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  name
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT birthday) > 1
```

<del>If `yes`, you need to find another record with the same name, but also a different colour AND a different birthday.

    SELECT
      Name
    FROM
      yourTable
    WHERE
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable as [lookup] WHERE Name = yourTable.Name AND Birthday  yourTable.Birthday AND Colour  yourTable.Colour)
    GROUP BY
      Name</del>

Comment: I am getting the following error message when I try this...
Column 'birthday' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Are you executing the query exactly as is, or are you changing it and adding the Birthday field in as well?

Comment: I am substituting column names for the actual column names in my table. I'm not sure what you mean by adding the Birthday field...

Comment: and the answer to the question in your answer is no, it is not possible to have two different birthdays for the same colour associated to the same name.

Comment: In my example query I `SELECT x` and also `GROUP BY x`.  If you change `x` in one, you must change `x` in the other as well; You can't `SELECT` what you don't `GROUP BY`.

Comment: sql doesn't work for - insert yourtable values('Mark','7/5','yellow')

Comment: Unless I mis-understand, `Mark` should still be output after that insert - There are still at least two colours associated to Mark which have different birthdays. (Blue & Green, or Blue & Yellow)

Comment: I guess it can also be comprehended that way. But how about insert yourTabl values('Pete','7/18','Blue')  ?

Comment: New name, only 1 birthday, doesn't count.  Until you add another record for Pete with a different Birthday.  (And accounting for the fact the the OP's comment that Pete/Blue can only ever have one birthday.)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select
    NAME
    FROM (select
              NAME
              FROM YourTable
              GROUP BY Name,Birthday
              HAVING Count(Name)=1
         ) dt
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(Name)>1
```

working sample code for SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (name varchar(10),Birthday varchar(10), FavoriteColor varchar(10))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Bob'  ,   '7/18'   ,    'Blue')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Bob'  ,   '7/18'   ,    'Green')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Mark' ,   '5/10'   ,    'Blue')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Mark' ,   '7/5'    ,    'Green')

select
    NAME
    FROM (select
              NAME
              FROM @YourTable
              GROUP BY Name,Birthday
              HAVING Count(Name)=1
         ) dt
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(Name)>1
```

OUTPUT:

```
NAME
----------
Mark
```

Comment: it is a difficult to understand question with a lot of ambiguity on the many possible exceptions and how to handle them.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. I just want to see the people who have different birthdays associated with different colors. What would you like me to clarify? Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: If you add the record `'Bob', '5/10', 'Red'`; Bob should now be included in the results, but won't be.

Comment: 0 rows returned with my testdata

Comment: @Dems, if you add `'Bob', '5/10', 'Red'` should it be displayed? what if you add a `'Jim', '5/12', 'purple'` should that be displayed as well?  what if you then add a `'Bob', '5/10', 'yellow'` will Bob still be displayed?  it is easy to change the code to account for all of these, but the specifications are vague on the details of how it should work.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, I just used your test data (which looks almost like an exact copy of my test data) and I got the same as my above listed `OUTPUT:`

Comment: @KM : My understanding is just what I've written in my answer, and it can be reduced down to `any name with more than one different birthday associated to it` on the grounds that he says (in a comment on my answer) that no colour can have more than one birthday per name.

Comment: @Dems, what about a name that only has a single row, does that count as a different birthday?

Comment: @KM: I'd suggest not.  Allowing for the algebraic manipulation allowed by "Any name/colour can appear on once, and so have only one birthday" I honestly think he means "Names with multiple different birthdays" or `GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT birthday) > 1`

Comment: @Dems, you are working WAY to hard for your 10 points here, you put in more effort than the Op did on the question. The question is ambiguous/vague and does not include adequate sample data.  As a result you are making assumptions.  you may be correct or you may not, I'm not going to split hairs with you.

Comment: @KM : LOL, I'm neither working nor looking for points.  But I'm most certainly a bit OCD and never let a discussion go; until it's either resolved or someone's head goes pop :)

Comment: Ok I really messed up. Since rows with the same name and color cannot have different birthdays, color is irrelevant. We're really just looking for distinct birthdays within a name. Hence
"GROUP BY
  name
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT birthday) > 1"
I really didn't realize how much confusion I was bringing into this when I included color. I will rewrite my question without color. I apologize for the confusion! This is my first time posting on something like this so I didn't have a great understanding of what information is relevant and what information isn't. Evidently, the color is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM table_xyz 
GROUP BY Name, Birthday
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

Comment: If Mark had just one birthday (and so implicitly just 1 colour) your query would still return Mark.

Comment: Mark can have the same birthday and two different colors. I want the people who have different birthdays associated with the different colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several different ways. You can either `JOIN` the table to itself, or you can use the `EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.name
FROM
    Some_Table AS T1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM Some_Table T2
            WHERE T2.name = T1.name AND
                  T2.birthday <> T1.birthday)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.name
FROM
    Some_Table AS T1
INNER JOIN Some_Table AS T2 ON
    T2.name = T1.name AND
    T2.birthday <> T1.birthday
```

You could also solve this particular problem using the `HAVING`clause:

```
SELECT
    T1.name
FROM
    Some_Table AS T1
GROUP BY
    T1.name
HAVING
    MAX(birthday) <> MIN(birthday)
```

Comment: I tested last sql, it didn't work try  - insert some_table values('Mark','7/5','yellow')